# How to combine gems from multiple Gemfiles to run one Ruby program?

Tags: ruby, heroku, rubygems, bundler, logstash

**My Question**

Suppose I have a directory structure like this:

```
app/
    core/
        bin/
            runner
        Gemfile
        ...
    Gemfile
    lib/
```

The "core" is an application which has its own Gemfile and Gemfile.lock. I don't want to modify core in any way. app/Gemfile is part of my plugin to core, which also has a Gemfile (listing its own dependencies that are additional to core/Gemfile).

I can "bundle install" from the app/core/ and app/ directories.

How can I run core/bin/runner from the app/ directory in such a way that it will include all the Ruby gems from both app/core/Gemfile and app/Gemfile?

**Background**

I am writing a plugin for Logstash, using C Ruby. Logstash includes its own Gemfile; once all dependencies are fetched, the total package size is about 40MB.

I want to run Logstash in Heroku. To avoid putting 40MB of stuff into Git, I have forked the Ruby buildpack (https://github.com/inscitiv/heroku-buildpack-logstash) and modified it to download Logstash, unpack it, and use its Gemfile.

This works fine, but I am stuck with the Gemfile provided by Logstash. For my plugins, I want to add new dependencies that my plugins will use; I don't really want to fork Logstash and change its Gemfile in order to accomplish this.

Instead, I want to unpack Logstash into its own directory (logstash/), and then I want to overlay my plugin code, including Gemfile for dependencies, on top of it. Then I want to run a Heroku "worker" process which will run logstash, specifying "." as the plugins directory, and has access to all the gems from both Gemfiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that the top-level Gemfile should include the child directory Gemfiles.

Something like this (from Redmine 2.0 Gemfile)

```
# Load plugins' Gemfiles
Dir.glob File.expand_path("../plugins/*/Gemfile", __FILE__) do |file|
  puts "Loading #{file} ..." if $DEBUG # `ruby -d` or `bundle -v`
  instance_eval File.read(file)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For bundler to work at getting all gem dependencies right, it really needs to have them all in one file.   Could you make your plugin into a gem and have your deploy routine add one gem to the parent Gemfile?  Your own gem can then list dependencies that would get incorporated into the whole.

Comment: One problem is that Heroku requires the Gemfile.lock to exist and be up to date. So I would have to fork Logstash and update the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock; which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: That's kinda the whole point of Bundler and Gemfiles - it locks the dependency tree together, at development time before even being put into source control.   Then upon deployment, it installs exactly the same environment.   The only way for it to do so means the top level Gemfile.lock must have all dependencies listed beforehand.  It sounds to me like you are trying to install a new door on an airplane while it is in flight.